# Is it required to disclose proprietary / closed source code of commercial software which utilizes open source CDDLv1.0 libraries?

Tags: commercial, law, distribution, java, cddl

I am working on a Java server side solution utilizing open source libraries (using jars ‘as-is’) released under CDDLv1.0 license. The open source libraries is either statically or dynamically bound in an combined archive / binary being sold. I publish license & notices as part of software documentation (viewable to users). When I distribute software to a customer, is it mandatory to publish proprietary source code as well under the CDDLv1.0 license? What are other considerations that legally I should be wary of and should take care before commercially distributing it?

Answer (score 2):

> When I distribute software to a customer, is it mandatory to publish proprietary source code as well under the CDDLv1.0 license?

The only code that must have sources published under the CDDL 1.0 license is the original library that came under that license and any modifications (edits, additions, deletions) you made to that library. Code that simply uses/links to the library is *not* required to be under the CDDL 1.0 license.

> What are other considerations that legally I should be wary of and should take care before commercially distributing it?

Most of it (mentioning copyrights and licenses) you already covered. One requirement from the CDDL 1.0 you did not yet cover is hat you must inform the users of your application where they can obtain the source code for the CDDL-covered portions of the application.